# How to add an item only when an incrementally executed target is run?

Tags: msbuild

Say we have the following MSBuild project that defines a target which can be partially run:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Foo">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MyInputs Include="**/*.json"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Foo"
        Condition="'@(MyInputs)' != ''"
        Inputs="@(MyInputs)"
        Outputs="@(MyInputs->'%(FileName).cs')">
    <MyCustomTask FileToProcess="%(MyInputs.Identity)"/>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="%(MyInputs.FileName).cs"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The problem is that *all* items are included into `ProcessedFiles`; even these whose respective `MyCustomTask`s are not run, due to incremental building. Apparently, MSBuild always processes `ItemGroup`s inside targets.

Is there a way to add an item inside a target, only when the respective target batch is run? I tried using `CreateItem`, because it is a task and might not get executed just like `MyCustomTask`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My specific problem was that when the source files had already existed, they were included twice in the `Compile` item, which raised a warning. It was then when I learned about [the `KeepDuplicates` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019#attributes-and-elements) that saved me.

But the question still stands.